# Media Query in Bootstrap using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use the following media query in my rails app.

```
    @media (min-width: 768px) {

   .center.navbar .nav, .center.navbar .nav > li {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
     vertical-align:top;
    width:100%;
    }

  .center .dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  text-align:left;

   }

 .center .dropdown.open ul {

 display: block;

   }
```

I am using bootstrap as my framework for the front end. Normally if I want to override a piece of Bootstrap CSS I put my code in the override stylesheet, however I am not sure where to put media queries. Ive tried the main stylesheet and also the override stylesheet but its not reading it. I’m sure I’m missing a basic rule here and would appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome is great for CSS priority debugging.

I have placed your the CSS in a `<style>` tag just before `</head>`

And added `.center` to `.navbar`

Then just right click on the `.navbar` and click on `Inspect Element`

You can navigate in your code on the bottom left side and if you click on `.nav` you can see on the bottom right side the css applied to your selection (you will recognise the media query).

The position of your css is not an issue, The priority is given to your override since  `.center.navbar` includes 2 classes and the default behaviour is only using 1 class.

[image: debug css with chrome]

make sure the class `.center` to `.navbar`.

**NOTE:**

For me there's 3 possible reason for your problem.

- the `.center` is missing (that's why i asked you to make sure `.center` exist)
- the cache serves the css and you need to clear the cache of your web browser.
- the media query is not present in the stylesheet (you can debug with chrome to prove it)

Comment: sorry @baptme didnt quite understand the last bit, thanks so much for your help again though. So what your saying is because the media query is of greater specificity than the default behaviour it is overwriting everything else?

Comment: @Richlewis the priority of css if defined by http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Training/Priority_level_of_selector, if two  elements have the same level of priority, the last declared wins. since your css have one more class used, it will always have the edge on the default behavior. And for that reason the position of the css cannot be an issue.

Comment: I'm so sorry to ask again but it doesn't matter what I do, I cant get it to behave the way I would like, is there a solution to this query? I now understand that because Im using .center to .navbar it is overriding the default behaviour, i just cant figure out how to change the media query to run and not override anything else

Comment: @RichLewis I think it will be easier to tell me what you want to acheive based on the working example http://46.32.253.11/

Comment: Hi again @baptme, ok so the navabr is fine on a desktop full screen, its when the responsive navbar button comes into effect, thats when the navbar gets messy.im sure you have noticed.. What i am trying to achieve is that when the navbar button is pressed all links are aligned to the left or center of page with no dropdown links showing, when a link is clicked the dropdowns will be revealed

Comment: @media (max-width: 979px) {
      .navbar  .dropdown-menu {display:none}
      .navbar .nav > li a:hover { background-color:transparent}
      .center.navbar .nav, .center.navbar .nav > li {display:table;clear:both};
     }

Comment: tried this in the browser, nothing changes. Can I ask how you got it to work?